# Woocommerce Custom Checkout

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic

I have website that's using woocommerce and what i want is to have a extra form before proceeding to checkout page.

to illustrate, 
when the user click "Proceed to Checkout" they will be redirected to a page which it has a form they need to fill up and then after submitting it they will be redirected to the Checkout Page.

Anyone knows how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom page and add that custom page url in below function. So all WP "Proceed to Checkout" will go to the custom page.

And in that page you can have a link to **Final Cart Page** and add the checkout link there.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'wpse_redirect_checkout');

function wpse_redirect_checkout($url) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $checkout_url = 'http://www.example.com/custom-checkout-page';
    return  $checkout_url; 
}
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention that the form will only be applicable if a specific item is added on the cart. for example, there is a product called warranty registration. if that product is on the cart when they click "Proceed to Checkout" they will be redirected to a form. if the product is not on the cart, just a normal checkout will be used.